# manage.py runserver Error: [Errno 10013]

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am having some problems running django. When I use the command `manage.py runserver` I receive an error that says: `Error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by access permissions`

I use postgreSQL as my database.

Edit: I run Windows Vista

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't have permission to bind to a socket, you can try `sudo manage.py runserver` to do it with root privileges.

With Windows Vista / 7 you need to run the shell with administrator privileges. You can right click on the icon and select "Run as administrator" or go to `c:\windows\system32\` and right click on `cmd.exe` and select "Run as administrator".

Edit: OK, this error occurs when another process is already using the same port. To change the port, do `manage.py runserver 8080` where the number at the end is the port you want.

Comment: sorry should have mention I run windows vista

Comment: @Zain: agf is half correct, you need to Run As Administrator in Windows to bind to privileged ports.

Comment: I also tried running as administer (the command prompt) but did not work

Comment: ok that worked. using manage.py runserver 8080 ran correctly. Thanks. I really appreciate you taking out some your time to help me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Windows8.1 (IPython 1.2.0 and Python 3.3.4).
I found this solution from https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1817 :

ipython notebook : start at port 8888

ipython notebook --port=1234 : use port 1234

Answer (score 0):

**

- [Errno 10013]

**
that error comes when the port you want to use is already in use by the another program.
so what you do just choose for another port which of which you can use port 8080
use the following commond
***python manage.py runserver 8080***

Comment: Place review whether your answer _adds any value to the existing answers_. From my point of view, your answer ('change port') is no different from the other, older answers ('change port').